# confusion regarding 301 redirect from folder to subfolder in web.config

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

Say I have my api under this url
`http://www.example.net/api/trythis` and I would like to redirect to `http://www.example.net/api/v1/trythis`, so in future I can have `http://www.example.net/api/v2/trythis` or `http://www.example.net/api/v3/trythis`

I am thinking of doing this in web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/api/*" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/api/v1/*" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

However, if someone access url `/api/v2/trythis or /ap1/v3/trythis`, won't they be redirected to `/api/v1/trythis`? So it will defeat the purpose of versioning?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f Create other rules in front of this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your rules, it will cause multiple redirect errors. Since the "api/v1" also matches the "api".

To solve this issue, you should set the condition in your url rewrite rule to avoid multiple matching.

Details, you could refer to below rule:

```
     <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="api/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://yousitedomain.com/api/v1/{R:1}"  />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="api/v1/(.*)"  negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
    </rule>
```

If you want to avoid v2,v3, I suggest you could add multiple condition as above setting.

Comment: Ok, so it is not a good idea to do 301 redirect then, as I don't want to change web.config every time a new version of API is created.

Comment: If you add enough condition in your url rewrite rule, you could use 301 redirect. Besides, if your api version is someting like v1 or v2 or v3, you could try this condition :  <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="api/v(.*)"  negate="true"/>. It will match all v api url.